# Symfony REST return files

Tags: rest, symfony, http

I'm creating a rest api in symfony 6. I'm sending a png file via http request, I'm saving the filename in the database and the file in a directory on the server. I need 2 endpoints in the controller. One to return all files to be able to display them on the front, and the other to return a specific photo. Something like that:
localhost:8080/api/images - get all images
localhost:8080/api/images/{$id} - gets specific image

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I don't know how to return these images. Should I generate a url to the image and send it back as json?

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your requirements. I recommend (1.).

**(1.)** Absolute path to image:

The advantage is that the client can decide for itself when the image is loaded. You could even make several image formats per image available to the client.

/api/images/{$id}

```json
{
  "image": "https://www.example.com/a_1.jpg",
  "image_other_view": "https://www.example.com/a_2.jpg"
}
```

/api/images

```json
[
  {
    "image": "https://www.example.com/a_1.jpg",
    "image_other_view": "https://www.example.com/a_2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "image": "https://www.example.com/b_1.jpg",
    "image_other_view": "https://www.example.com/b_2.jpg"
  }
]
```

**(2.)** Data stream:

You can only return one file in a data stream. https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#serving-files

/api/images/{$id}

```php
return new BinaryFileResponse('/path/to/file/a_1.jpg');
```

Comment: ok, and how can I generate this path for the file. I'm currently using docker and the link to my api is localhost:8080.
The endpoint for this controller is /api/images.
photos are located in the /public/assets/images directory